# Transitioning element from different positions

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to take an element, and on a binary event, move the element off the page my moving it to the left. I can accomplish this easily. However, when the binary event occurs again, I want to take this element and return it to its original position, but this time have it come in from the right side of the page.

See the below snippet. Essentially, when Essentially going from ON to OFF, I want to render box 1. When going from OFF to ON, I want to render box 2. How am I able to accomplish this if my element can only transition between two given positions? Thanks.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      onClick: true,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      onClick: !this.state.onClick
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.onClick ? "ON" : "OFF"}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
        <div id={this.state.onClick ? "box1A" : "box1B"}>BOX 1</div>
        <div id={this.state.onClick ? "box2A" : "box2B"}>BOX 2</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

```css
#box1A {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  transition: left linear 1.0s;
}

#box1B {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  transition: left linear 1.0s;
}

#box2A {
  background-color: red;
  top: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 340px;
  transition: right linear 1.0s;
}

#box2B {
  background-color: red;
  top: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -200px;
  transition: right linear 1.0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: So basically if I understand correctly you only want one box that goes to the left and comes from the right?

Comment: Correct. One box that leaves to the left and enters from the right, only to leave again to the left, and so on.

Comment: you can do this with css3 animations keyframes, do you want me to offer an example?

Comment: Thanks @Stephen but I think I'm going to go with react-transition-group instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use [react-transition-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/), it allows you to give it a `className` and it will append the appropriate animation hooks like, `enter`, `enter-active`, `leave` and `leave-active`.

Checkout the examples in that page.